# Numpy array, how to test if a value is the local minimum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d Numpy array like:

```
array([[0.87, 0.13, 0.18, 0.04, 0.79],
       [0.07, 0.58, 0.84, 0.82, 0.76],
       [0.12, 0.77, 0.68, 0.58, 0.8 ],
       [0.43, 0.2 , 0.57, 0.91, 0.01],
       [0.43, 0.74, 0.56, 0.11, 0.58]])
```

I'd like to test each number to evaluate if it is the local minima within a window of x*y, for example, a 3x3 window would return this

```
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

I want to avoid using a native python loop, since my array is quite large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.minimum_filter.html) to compute the 2D minima, then perform a comparison to the original:

```
from scipy.ndimage import minimum_filter

mins = minimum_filter(a, mode='constant', size=(3,3), cval=np.inf)

a==mins # or np.isclose(a, mins)
```

output:

```
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

intermediate `mins`:

```
array([[0.07, 0.07, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04],
       [0.07, 0.07, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04],
       [0.07, 0.07, 0.2 , 0.01, 0.01],
       [0.12, 0.12, 0.11, 0.01, 0.01],
       [0.2 , 0.2 , 0.11, 0.01, 0.01]])
```